# Wordpress get post variable sent on edit user page by admin

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I want to detect in my plugin (or functions.php), if a variable POST is just sent.
I mean, when the admin change the role of a user, the variable post ROLE is sent.

```
<select name="role" id="role">
<option value="shop_manager">Shop manager</option>
<option value="customer">Customer</option>
<option selected="selected" value="level_1">Level 1</option>
<option value="subscriber">Subscriber</option>
<option value="contributor">Contributor</option>
<option value="author">Author</option>
<option value="editor">Editor</option>
<option value="administrator">Administrator</option><option value="">— No role for this site —</option>
```

```
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'CheckPost', 10, 1);//loading on user-edit.php

$rolemodified = $_POST['role'];
function CheckPost(){
if( !empty($rolemodified) ){ echo "ROLE: $rolemodified ";  } 
}
```

I want to retrieve this $_POST['role']; or show it on an alert

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('post:');</script>";
```

Thanks

Comment: Just mash the two lines you have together into this: `if( !empty($rolemodified) ){ echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$rolemodified');</script>";  }`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is that $rolemodified ($_POST['role']) is not detecting, so its empty. If the admin change the role, there must be a $_POST['role'] var sent, so I want to get his value during or after the update user information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a [variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue.

`$rolemodified` is not available within your function.

Try to add it as a global variable in your function like this:

```
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'CheckPost', 10, 1);//loading on user-edit.php

$rolemodified = $_POST['role'];
function CheckPost() {
    global $rolemodified; // or set $rolemodified here
    if( !empty($rolemodified) ){ echo "ROLE: $rolemodified ";  } 
}
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed that you are also using the `edit_user_profile` hook. You will need to use the `edit_user_profile_update` hook to get the post values.

Comment: I was thinking on an scope problem. What you said is an scope in the function, I think is a problem on a scope in the whole document. I am in a "custom plugin functions page", so maybe is not recognizing the vars... I did what you said, but still nothing. Thanks